# Can you use back references in the pattern part of a regular expression?

Tags: php, regex, backreference

Is there a way to back reference in the regular expression pattern?

**Example input string:**

```
Here is "some quoted" text.
```

Say I want to pull out the quoted text, I could create the following expression:

```
"([^"]+)"
```

This regular expression would match `some quoted`.

Say I want it to also support single quotes, I could change the expression to:

```
["']([^"']+)["']
```

But what if the input string has a mixture of quotes say `Here is 'some quoted" text.` I would not want the regex to match. Currently the regex in the second example would still match.

What I would like to be able to do is if the first quote is a double quote then the closing quote must be a double. And if the start quote is single quote then the closing quote must be single.

Can I use a back reference to achieve this?

---

*My other related question: [Getting text between quotes using regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723325/getting-text-between-quotes-using-regular-expression)*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can make use of the regex:

```
(["'])[^"']+\1
```

- `()` : used for grouping
- `[..]` : is the char class. so `["']`
  matches either `"` or `'` equivalent
  to `"|'`
- `[^..]` : char class with negation.
  It matches any char not listed after
  the `^`
- `+` : quantifier for one or more
- `\1` : backreferencing the first
  group which is `(["'])`

In `PHP` you'd use this as:

```
preg_match('#(["\'])[^"\']+\1#',$str)
```

Comment: somehow doesnt work.... are backreferences still supported?

Answer (score 2):

```
preg_match('/(["\'])([^"\']+)\1/', 'Here is \'quoted text" some quoted text.');
```

Explanation: `(["'])([^"']+)\1/` I placed the first quote in parentheses. Because this is the first grouping, it's back reference number is 1. Then, where the closing quote would be, I placed \1 which means *whichever character was matched in group 1.*

Answer (score 0):

`/"\(.*?\)".*?\1/` should work, but it depends on the regular expression engine

Answer (score 0):

This is old. But you need to provide the `$matches` variable in `preg_match($pattern, $subject, &$matches)`
Then you can use it `var_dump($matches)`

see https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match