# Getting text between quotes using regular expression

Tags: php, regex, string

I'm having some issues with a regular expression I'm creating.

I need a regex to match against the following examples and then sub match on the first quoted string:

**Input strings**

`("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.")`

`('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. ')`

`('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. ', 'arg1', "arg2")`

**Must sub match**

`Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.`

**Regex so far:**

`\((["'])([^"']+)\1,?.*\)`

The regex does a sub match on the text between the first set of quotes and returns the sub match displayed above.

This is almost working perfectly, but the problem I have is that if the quoted string contains quotes in the text the sub match stops at the first instance, see below:

**Failing input strings**

`("Lorem ipsum dolor \"sit\" amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.")`

Only sub matches: `Lorem ipsum dolor`

`("Lorem ipsum dolor 'sit' amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.")`

The entire match fails.

**Notes**

The input strings are actually php code function calls. I'm writing a script that will scan .php source files for a specific function and grab the text from the first parameter.

Comment: Why not jsut use the Reflection API? Edit: nevermind... you mean youre scanning the actual script not the functions/classes/etc..

Comment: Correct. I'm scanning the source looking for the above strings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this regular expression:

```
\(\s*(?:"(?:[^"\\]+|\\.)*"|'(?:[^'\\]+|\\.)*')(?:\s*,\s*(?:"(?:[^"\\]+|\\.)*"|'(?:[^'\\]+|\\.)*'))*\s*\)
```

Some explanation:

- **`\(\s\*`** matches the opening parenthesis and optional whitespace.
- **`(?:"(?:[^"\\]+|\\.)*"|'(?:[^'\\]+|\\.)*')`** is to match any quoted string allowing the quote character only when escaped with `\`.
- **`(?:\s*,\s*(?:"(?:[^"\\]+|\\.)*"|'(?:[^'\\]+|\\.)*'))*`** describes zero or more quotes strings, preceded by a `,` that may be preceded and followed by whitespace.
- **`\s*\)`** matches the closing parenthesis with optional whitespace.

Comment: Can't get this to work fully. I'm getting an error regarding a missing paren at position 46?

Answer (score 0):

make sure to not match a quote when it is escaped (has a backslash before it):

```
/\((["'])([^"']+)[^\\]\1,?.*?\)/
```