# Regex matching beginning AND end strings where the two strings are same

Tags: php, regex, string

I have the following code:

```
<?php
    $subject="something";
    $pattern="something";
    If(preg_match($pattern,$subject)){
        echo "Match is found";
    }else{
        echo "Match is not found";
    }
?>
```

If I have

```
$subject="apple is fruit and I love apple";
```

The main point being the string beginning with `apple` and ending with `apple`

Then what should be the pattern so that

`match is found`

is the output.

I know the pattern can be

```
"/^apple.*apple$/"
```

But I don't want to repeat the same word apple.

Comment: You don't want to repeat the substring `"apple"`? Put it in a variable: `$word = "apple";`, or use `sprintf` to build your pattern.

Comment: This cannot be the answer as then I have to repeat $word variable

Comment: I think you want something like this:

    ^(\w+)\b.*\b\1$

Basically, start with a word (\w+) and then a word boundary.  Whatever is in the (\w+) must then be at the end, which is the \1    I'm not sure what the \1 syntax is in php, this is for Python.  Maybe $1 ?

Comment: You don't have to do it with `sprintf`

Comment: maybe try `/^apple((?!apple).)+apple$/m`

Comment: you want to match all the string that starts with apple and ends with apple ???

Comment: i think he wants strings that start with apple, and ends with apple, but otherwise doesn't contain the word apple

Comment: Maybe https://eval.in/814950 or it has to be 1 regex?

Comment: I feel OP needs `"/^(apple).*(?1)$/s"` (due to *I don't want to repeat the same word apple.*)

Comment: @ForDev you are  correct, but in middle it may or may not have apple, just the beginning  and end should have apple

Comment: @cyano_learner if that's the case, then your current regex already does the job.

Comment: @hanshenrik yeah it does, that's where my question is, that is there any other way to achieve the same by not repeating the word apple

Comment: @cyano_learner It may or may not have apple in the middle? I thought apple was not allowed in the middle?

Comment: `$pattern = sprintf('/^%1$s.*%1$s$/', 'apple');` like this?

Comment: in that case, i think @WiktorStribiżew is correct (what a weird requirement though)

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte you are not getting me,  here you are repeating %1$s but I am wondering if there is any shortcut where there is absolutely no repitetion

Comment: what could possibly require you not to repeat the word?  are you in a code obfuscation contest? but i still think @WiktorStribiżew is correct.

Comment: Yeah that's why I have voted him up?

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure if I should post that or not. I bet there is a dupe post, but cannot find it.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Is there an advantage to using recurse over backreference?

Comment: @chris85: Only in case `apple` is in fact a placeholder for some other pattern, e.g. `<<[A-Z]{3}>>`. But not really sure, the question is rather weird. I just do not see any issue. Closing it as primarily opinion-based.

Comment: Actually I thought that repetetion means longer coding, so any shortcut if present is better, like in c language, rather than writing b=b+1 we write b++

Comment: You just need a [backreference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722472/can-you-use-back-references-in-the-pattern-part-of-a-regular-expression). Try: /^(\w+).*(\1)$/

Comment: It's super unclear to me why this extremely simple question garnered so much discussion. The question has been answered, it's customary to accept one of the answers or explain why the answers don't satisfy your question.

Answer (score 0):

You just need a [backreference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722472/can-you-use-back-references-in-the-pattern-part-of-a-regular-expression). Try:

```
/^(\w+).*(\1)$/
```

The `(\w+)` captures the first word, no matter what it is, without having to specify "apple" as the word. The backreference, `\1` tells the regex parser to substitute in whatever was captured in the first capture group. Using the magic of [backtracking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9011592/in-regular-expressions-what-is-a-backtracking-back-referencing), the regex parser will figure out how to fit match the input symbols correctly to satisfy the backreference.